# JTable remove row by clicking a cell with a custom DeleteCellEditor from the same JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

In a class called `HistoryPanel` I have a static JTable called `resultsTable` with a static DefaultTableModel called `tableModel`. The table has a custom cell editor:

```
resultsTable.getColumn("Delete").setCellEditor(new DeleteButtonEditor(new JCheckBox()));
```

Inside, naturally, I override these two methods like this:

```
public Object getCellEditorValue()
{
    if (isPushed)
    {
        HistoryPanel.tableModel.removeRow(HistoryPanel.resultsTable.getSelectedRow());
    }
}

protected void fireEditingStopped()
{
    super.fireEditingStopped();
}
```

The exception is being thrown ONLY when I try to remove the last row of the resultsTable. When I'm removing a row that is not the last one it works perfectly. The exception is:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1 >= 1
```

And the line of code that causes the exception is:

```
super.fireEditingStopped();
```

Can anyone help me? How can I avoid this exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you remove the row you are editing during the edit operation. It would be a lot easier if you had posted an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) so I could test my proposed solution, but now I will leave that up to you.

I assume that wrapping your

```
if (isPushed)
{
    HistoryPanel.tableModel.removeRow(HistoryPanel.resultsTable.getSelectedRow());
}
```

inside an `EventQueue.invokeLater` call might solve the issue. That way editing is finished when you remove the row.

Comment: @HristoValchevHristov then consider [accepting the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) so that others can see this question is solved

Answer (score 1):

Really why not use `Boolean` value directly, why is there `Editor for JCheckBox`, you have to check tutorial [how the JTable works](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender)

EDIT

for real `TableCellEditor` you have to call

```
int row = table.convertRowIndexToModel(table.getEditingRow());
fireEditingStopped();
```

and thenafter you can call for delete